# JSON to HTML: Make Templates depending on JSON field value (ES6 only)

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator, template-literals

I'm trying to iterate over a nested JSON object using `.map()` and output different **HTML Templates** depending on the JSON `inputType: "value"`. I want to use the correct template *(es6 template literal)* based on a **Ternary Operator** and stamp the correct HTML to the DOM.

I've gotten pretty far, but I'm running into an issue with **Level 6** (form template) and **Level 7** (input templates). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/GxENOr

[image]

**JS** (the full javascript was omitted..please see [codepen](https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/GxENOr))

```
/* FORM (Level 6)
⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼ */
function formTEMPLATE(form) {
  return `
  ${form.map(function(form) {
    return `
      ${form.inputType['text'] ? textfieldTEMPLATE(form.inputType) : ''}
      ${form.inputType['select'] ? selectTEMPLATE(form.inputType) : ''}
      ${form.inputType['radio'] ? radioTEMPLATE(form.inputType) : ''}
      ${form.inputType['checkbox'] ? checkboxTEMPLATE(form.inputType) : ''}
    `}).join('')}`
}


/* ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ INPUT TEMPLATES ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ */


/* TEXTFIELDS (Level 7)
⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼ */
function textfieldTEMPLATE(text) {
  return `
    ${text.map(function(text) {
     return `
        <label>${text.labelText}</label>
        <input type="${text.inputType}" id="${text.inputId} name="${text.inputClass}">
    `}).join('')}`
}

/* SELECT MENU (Level 7)
⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼ */
function selectTEMPLATE(select) {
  return `
  <select class="select">
      ${select.map(function(select) {
       return `
          <option id="${select.inputID} name="${select.inputGROUP}" ${select.inputOPTION}">${select.inputLABEL}</option>
      `}).join('')}
  </select>`
}

/* RADIO (Level 7)
⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼ */
function radioTEMPLATE(radio) {
  return `
  <ul class="radio">
      ${radio.map(function(radio) {
       return `
        <li>
          <input type="${radio.inputTYPE}" id="${radio.inputID}" name="${radio.inputGROUP}" ${radio.inputOPTION}>
          <label for="${radio.inputID}">${radio.inputLABEL}</label>
        </li>
      `}).join('')}
  </ul>` 
}

/* CHECKBOX (Level 7)
⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼⎼ */
function checkboxTEMPLATE(checkbox) {
  return `
  <ul class="checkbox">
      ${checkbox.map(function(checkbox) {
       return `
        <li>
          <input type="${checkbox.inputTYPE}" id="${checkbox.inputID}" name="${checkbox.inputGROUP}" ${checkbox.inputOPTION}>
          <label for="${checkbox.inputID}">${checkbox.inputLABEL}</label>
        </li>
      `}).join('')}
  </ul>`
}
```

**JSON** (the full json was omitted..please see [codepen](https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/GxENOr))

```
[
  {
    "appLabel": "App",
    "appFolders": [
      {
        "folderLabel": "Folder",
        "folderFiles": [
          {
            "fileLabel": "File",
            "fileSections": [
              {
                "sectionLabel": "Select Menu",
                "sectionGroups": [
                  {
                    "groupLabel": "Group",
                    "groupInputs": [
                      {
                        "labelText": "Select 1",
                        "inputType": "select",
                        "inputId": "select1",
                        "inputClass": "select-1",
                        "inputCollection": [
                          {
                            "collectionLabelText": "Option 1",
                            "collectionInputType": "select",
                            "collectionInputId": "option1",
                            "collectionInputClass": "option-1",
                            "collectionInputName": "select-name-1"
                          },
```

Comment: what issue you met?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question?

Comment: My "form inputs" aren't displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.inputType['text'] ? textfieldTEMPLATE(form.inputType) : ''`

the issue here is that `form.inputType` has a string value .. `text` | `select` etc ... but that code checks if `form.inputType` has a **property** called `text` ... it doesn't ...

so, perhaps you want `form.inputType == 'text' ? textfieldTEMPLATE(form.inputType) : ''`

However, that's only one problem solved... the other is what you do inside `textfieldTEMPLATE` etc ... performing `.map` on the passed in **string** ... strings don't have a map method

So, you want to change as follows: note, the `*TEMPLATE` functions are called with the parameter `form`, not `form.inputType` - because `form` is an `object` with useful properties to create the elements, whereas `form.inputType` is a string, and not helpful for what you want to do

```
function formTEMPLATE(form) {
    return `${form.map(function(form) {
        return `
            ${form.inputType == 'text' ? textfieldTEMPLATE(form) : ''}
            ${form.inputType == 'select' ? selectTEMPLATE(form) : ''}
            ${form.inputType == 'radio' ? radioTEMPLATE(form) : ''}
            ${form.inputType == 'checkbox' ? checkboxTEMPLATE(form) : ''}
        `}
    ).join('')}`;
}

function textfieldTEMPLATE(text) {
    return `
        <label>${text.labelText}</label>
        <input type="${text.inputType}" id="${text.inputId} name="${text.inputClass}">
        <br />
    `;
}

function selectOptionTEMPLATE(options) {
    return options.inputCollection.map(function(option) {
        return `<option id="${option.collectionInputId} name="${option.collectionInputName}" ${option.collectionInputOption || ''}">${option.collectionLabelText}</option>`
    }).join('');
}

function selectTEMPLATE(select) {
    return `<select class="select">${selectOptionTEMPLATE(select)}</select>`;
}

function cbRadioTEMPLATE(x) {
    return x.inputCollection.map(function(input) {
        return `<li>
            <input type="${x.inputType}" id="${input.collectionInputId}" name="${input.collectionInputName}" ${input.collectionInputOption || ''}>
            <label for="${input.collectionInputId}">${input.collectionLabelText}</label>
        </li>`;
    }).join('');
}

function radioTEMPLATE(radio) {
    return `<ul class="radio">${cbRadioTEMPLATE(radio)}</ul>`;
}

function checkboxTEMPLATE(checkbox) {
    return `<ul class="checkbox">${cbRadioTEMPLATE(checkbox)}</ul>`;;
}
```

Note the function `function cbRadioTEMPLATE(x)` - because both checkbox and radio buttons use that code for the "list" of boxes - DRY code FTW :p

See it working at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWpqRw

> using arrow functions the above code can be simplified to

```
const formTEMPLATE = form => form.map(item => `
  ${item.inputType == "text" ? textfieldTEMPLATE(item) : ""}
  ${item.inputType == "select" ? selectTEMPLATE(item) : ""}
  ${item.inputType == "radio" ? radioTEMPLATE(item) : ""}
  ${item.inputType == "checkbox" ? checkboxTEMPLATE(item) : ""}
`).join("");

const textfieldTEMPLATE = text => `<label>${text.labelText}</label><input type="${text.inputType}" id="${text.inputId} name="${text.inputClass}"><br/>`;

const selectOptionTEMPLATE = options => options.inputCollection.map(option => `
  <option id="${option.collectionInputId} name="${option.collectionInputName}" ${option.collectionInputOption || ""}">${option.collectionLabelText}</option>
`).join("");

const selectTEMPLATE = select =>`<select class="select">${selectOptionTEMPLATE(select)}</select>`;

const cbRadioTEMPLATE = x => x.inputCollection.map(input => `
  <li><input type="${x.inputType}" id="${input.collectionInputId}" name="${input.collectionInputName}" ${input.collectionInputOption || ""}>
    <label for="${input.collectionInputId}">${input.collectionLabelText}</label>
  </li>
`).join("");

const radioTEMPLATE = radio => `<ul class="radio">${cbRadioTEMPLATE(radio)}</ul>`;

const checkboxTEMPLATE = checkbox =>`<ul class="checkbox">${cbRadioTEMPLATE(checkbox)}</ul>`;
```

And another optimisation is

```
const typeMap = {
  text: textfieldTEMPLATE,
  select: selectTEMPLATE,
  radio: radioTEMPLATE,
  checkbox: checkboxTEMPLATE
};
const formTEMPLATE = form => form.map(item => `${typeMap[item.inputType](item)}`).join("");
```

Comment: odd thing, you say ES6 only in the title, and you don't use `=>` to make your code a little more succinct

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'm digging into everything now and it's looking solid

Comment: I'm still condensing it

Comment: thanks a lot! I'm always trying to simplify the code down as much as it can be..that's why i stated that i wanted to only use es6. With the other optimizations you're doing, it's really helping to understand everything a lot clearer

Comment: One thing I noticed that made the code a bit difficult to read (due to prettified code) things like `return \`
  ${form.map(function(form) {...}).join("")}\`;` ... having the form.map inside the template string just made it less readable (to me) ... compare with `return form.map(function(form) {...}).join("");` - same result (I think?!?)

Comment: Right..I noticed that too from the first version. Well, I'm going to take a hard look at your optimizations and study exactly what you did. Because you you've basically shrunk the code down by 100 lines, and for that I'm forever grateful :D

Comment: Of course less lines isn't always a good thing. It still needs to be readable. I think it still is,  but others may disagree.